# Fastest String Format conversion

Tags: java, string, performance, date, formatting

I have the following string: `20140420000001`
I want to format it to: `2014-04-20+00:00:01`

What is the fastest possible way to do this in Java?

**Anything faster than this?**

```
String dt = "20140420000001";
System.out.println(dt.substring(0, 4)+"-"+dt.substring(4, 6)+"-"+dt.substring(6, 8)+"+"+dt.substring(8, 10)+":"+dt.substring(10, 12)+":"+dt.substring(12, 14));
```

Comment: Using a `SimpleDateFormat`. And forget about premature optimization, this is not a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I've seen occasions when date parsing/formatting really *has* been a bottleneck - but I'd definitely do it simply first and only look for the "fastest possible way" after *proving* that it's a bottleneck in a particular situation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if the op just wants to insert `-` `+` and `:` at some fixed positions in the string, there is probably no need for a simpledateformat.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you, specially when processing complex date patterns. In this example, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @assylias: I would argue that using `SimpleDateFormat` *explains* the code more than just adding punctuation - as well as performing validation.

Comment: The format is going to be fixed and my application receives close to 10000 requests per second so I am trying to optimize at every step.

Comment: @JonSkeet validation is not important as the data is fetched from a mysql database instance and it is already validated.

Comment: @AngryPanda "*the data is fetched from a mysql database*" ==> then you should receive them as dates in your code and format the dates.

Comment: @assylias - As a performance measure, I have stored dates in the format shown above. If I use a date object in the database table, then my query processing time increases by 3x.

Comment: @AngryPanda That's very surprising - dates are generally stored as a long (64 bit integer) in database and are much faster to process than strings. I would reconsider that choice if performance is important and make sure you used an appropriate date type and profile the query that was slow to find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

```
    return new String(new char[] {
            s.charAt(0), s.charAt(1), s.charAt(2), s.charAt(3),
            '-', s.charAt(4), s.charAt(5),
            '-', s.charAt(6), s.charAt(7),
            '+', s.charAt(8), s.charAt(9),
            ':', s.charAt(10), s.charAt(11),
            ':', s.charAt(12), s.charAt(13)
    });
```

Not too pretty, but there is hardly anything faster in pure Java.